# JSON Schema validator with an array of specific objects (different types)

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following JSON data that I would like to validate.

```
[
    { "fieldType": "oneThing" },
    { "fieldType": "anotherThing" },
    { "fieldType": "oneThing" }
]
```

And my current (non working) schema is:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "oneOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/oneThing" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/anotherThing" }
    ]
  },
  "definitions": {
    "oneThing": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fieldType": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "oneThing"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "fieldType"
      ]
    },
    "anotherThing": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "fieldType": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "anotherThing"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "fieldType"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error but I fail to see what I'm doing wrong.

`[] Object value found, but an array is required`

More context: I'm generating a dynamic HTML form based on a JSON configuration. The HTML form will have a specific set of valid field types and the same field type may exist multiple times in the config, thus `oneThing` appearing more than once in the above sample json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this had nothing to do with my JSON schema but with how I was calling the library that was parsing the schema.

I'm using https://github.com/justinrainbow/json-schema and was passing the wrong data type to the class. Duh!